# web setup wizard missing showing white page in magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3, backup, web-setup-wizard

To use the Magento setup wizard I logged into  Admin account and navigate to
 `System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard`
But
https://dev.mywebsite.com/setup/
Url showing `500 Internal Server Error`

I checked it in fresh version of magento2.2.3 on localhost it is working.
but on my server I upgraded my website in magento2.2.3 before few days so it is not working in my website of same version.

Comment: File permissions are correct?

Comment: which file permission?

Comment: On the webserver

Comment: You can tell files folder or file path on webserver?

Comment: Magento_Root/setup?

Comment: checking wait please

Comment: files have 664 and folder 755

Comment: Owner and group, needs to be set to the filesystem owner

Comment: I think is not permission issue because same website is set on localhost and same issue showing

Comment: @JugalKishor Please Check Error Log file

Comment: Also, are you using windows?

Comment: yes I am using windows and mac

Answer (score 0):

It working
Go to app/etc/env.php and change the following code from

`'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'db',
  ),`

to 
`'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),`